# Share localstorage across subdomains for specific user

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, subdomain

`User1` has access to both `company1.site.com` and `company2.site.com`.

So when User1 logs in to `company1.site.com` it will save it's Auth token to LocalStorage, but if `User1` will switch to `company2.site.com` the local storage will be empty hence he will have to Auth again.

How can i transfer token between subdomain's storage system?

Jira has i think what I'm looking for, when you have `organization.jira.com` and you can switch between those without having to re-login.

Comment: any code you tried

Comment: maybe they use cookies rather then localstorage to authenticate users.
You need to look into cookies and how to manage it on multiple subdomain having same parent domain ,also look into the term `LDAP`.